# How to monitor running screen session and start a new session once last one ended?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnu-screen

To run my neural network training, I start different training configurations using the following scripts:

NNtrain.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start 1st screen"
screen -dmS NN48001 bash -c '../NNrun.sh NN48001 hyperparam_48_001.json 0 0.5'
echo "Start 2nd screen"
screen -dmS NN480001 bash -c '../NNrun.sh NN480001 hyperparam_48_0001.json 0 0.5'
echo "Start 3rd screen"
screen -dmS NN4800001 bash -c '../NNrun.sh NN4800001 hyperparam_48_00001.json 1 0.5'
echo "Start 4th screen"
screen -dmS NN48000001 bash -c '../NNrun.sh NN48000001 hyperparam_48_000001.json 2 0.5'
```

NNrun.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f "/opt/anaconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
    . "/opt/anaconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate PyTorchNN
    echo "Activated conda env"
fi
echo $1
python main_broad_FEA.py --hyperparam-json $2 --GPU $3 --varstop $4
```

Now, I have 3GPUs in my machine and would like to batch-train more networks i.e. start the next training after the last one ended. Thus, I would like to monitor which screen-sessions have closed i.e. returned and then start a new screen session using the GPU used by the screen session that just ran.

**How can I check if and which of my screen sessions returned, so that I can start the next one using a bash script?**

(Note: If it unnecessarily more complicated doing this in a bash script, then please feel free to propose a suitable alternative.)

Comment: Why do you use `screen` at all? Does the script require any manual input? This looks like you want to use `xargs -P4` or GNUs `parallel`

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you for your answer. I have no experience with either of the two, and hence haven't thought of doing it this way. I will look into it.

Comment: @KamilCuk Question: Is there a way for me to connect to individual parallel sessions and monitor the progress? Since I am training neural networks each thread is very computation intensive and may be running anywhere from 30min to multiple days, it would be desirable to be able to check on the intermediate output during the training, and also abort a training if something went wrong, without aborting all trainings.

Comment: In that case I say do aim to use `screen`. You need to do something with each job separately, so that's the way. But you have to script it yourself, write all the logic to "check which process returned so that you can start the next one". If it takes several days, I would rather create a drop-in systemd service file, so that I can manage (stop/restart) it easily and that journald takes care of logging. I imaging you could also add dependencies for drop-in service in systemd, wonder if that could create the whole process tree in single go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

doit() {
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
      . "/opt/anaconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
      CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate PyTorchNN
      echo "Activated conda env"
    fi
    echo $1
    python main_broad_FEA.py --hyperparam-json $2 --GPU $3 --varstop $4
}
export -f doit

parallel -j 3 {1} {2} {%} {3} ::: a r g 1 ::: a r g 2 ::: a r g 4
```

Explanation:

- "-j 3" defines the number of job slots
- "{1}" is replaced by the respective element from "arg1" - likewise for {2} and {3}
- {%} is the job slot number. We use this to determine which GPU to run on. (See page 30 of https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014)
- ":::" is followed by a list of arguments (one per job)

If you want to monitor the running jobs live, you can do that using `tmux`:

```
parallel --tmux -j 3 {1} {2} {%} {3} ::: a r g 1 ::: a r g 2 ::: a r g 4
```

Comment: Hi @Ole Tange, I am honored to have you answer this. Could you please briefly clarify what is happening in the last line?

Comment: @avgJoe Please spend 15 minutes reading chapter 2: https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014 and then elaborate on which parts of the line you do not understand.

Comment: I tried to add the clarification, please correct me if I misunderstood something. But, how does this handle the load balancing on the GPU? And how does it call the doit() function? Given that I have a queue of tasks that I want to process, and simply start a new task on the GPU that was freed up last, how does this command ensure that happens?

Answer (score 0):

As I presented my question above, I was over-complicating the problem.

The solution that I used in the end, was to add `touch "$3.GPUFREE"` to the end of my NNrun.sh script. This creates an empty file ".GPUFREE" when the NNrun.sh script terminates. Finally, I  run a loop that checks if a ".GPUFREE" file was created from my NNtrain.sh and thus know which GPU was freed up. Then the script just deleted the file and starts the next job on that GPU.